# Segmented Data Load: Table records to xml

Tags: c#, datatable, performance

I have a sequence of sql queries that result in very large datasets that I have to query against a database and write them to files. I have about 80 queries and each one produces somewhere between 1000 records to  10,000,000 records. I cannot change the queries themselves. What I'm trying to do is read 500,000 records at a time for each query and write to a file. Here's what I have so far

```
void WriteXml(string tableName, string queryString)
{
    int pageSize = 500000;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    using (
       SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                int rowsRead = 0, count = 0, index = 0;
                do
                {
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("SomeDatasetName");
                    rowsRead = dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, currentIndex, pageSize, tableName);
                    currentIndex += rowsRead;
                    if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && rowsRead > 0)
                    {
                        dataSet.Tables[0].WriteXml(string.Format(@"OutputXml\{0}_{1}.xml", tableName, index++),
                                                   XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
                    }
                }
                while (rowsRead > 0);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works but it's very very slow. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here because when I run it, the application hogs up most of my memory (I have 6GB) and it takes for ever to run. I started it last night and it is still running. I understand I'm dealing with a lot a records but I don't think it's something that would take so many hours to run.

Is this the right way to do paged/segmented data read from a database? Is there any way this method could be optimized or is there any other way I can approach this?

Do let me know if I'm not clear on anything and I'll try to provide clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paging overloads for DataAdapter.Fill still get the entire result set beneath the covers. Read here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f%28vs.71%29.aspx

the part that pertains to your question:

> The DataAdapter provides a facility for returning only a page of data,
>   through overloads of the Fill method. However, this might not be the
>   best choice for paging through large query results because, while the
>   DataAdapter fills the target DataTable or DataSet with only the
>   requested records, the resources to return the entire query are still
>   used. To return a page of data from a data source without using the
>   resources required to return the entire query, specify additional
>   criteria for your query that reduces the rows returned to only those
>   required.

In Linq2Sql, there are convenient methods Skip and Take for paging through data. You could roll your own by using a parameterized query constructed to do the same thing. Here is an example to skip 100, and take 20 rows:

```
SELECT TOP 20 [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName],
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 100 [t1].[CustomerID]
        FROM [Customers] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[City] = @p0
        ORDER BY [t1].[CustomerID]
        ) AS [t2]
    WHERE [t0].[CustomerID] = [t2].[CustomerID]
    ))) AND ([t0].[City] = @p1)
ORDER BY [t0].[CustomerID]
```

Comment: Neat idea but it's not feasible for me to change individual queries. If only there was a generic way to skip and take.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that would not require modifying your stored procedures would be asynchronous queries like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379553 although I don't know how much that would help.